# "restart" is to "restarted", "shutdown" is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests

If *"restart"* is to *"restarted"*, *"shutdown"* is to what?

I don't think *shutdowned* is the word. What is the past-tense of the word *shutdown*?

Comment: Are you trying to say that in the past the computer was shut down? Or are you trying to say it is now shut down? "Restart" refers to an operation that completes while "shutdown" refers to entering a state that persists. It's not clear, at least to me, how they are analogous to make your question work. If you just mean it was shut down in the past, then "was shut down", just like "was restarted".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*"Shutdown"* as a verb is probably best rendered as *shut down*, in which case the past tense would be *shut down*. See [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shutdown).

Comment: From a non native point of view, strictly grammatical shut-shut-shut irregular verb (http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/irregular-verbs/shut.html). Restart your computer. The restarted computer is brand new. Shutdown your computer. The shutdown computer is brand new.

Comment: As a past particle used as an adjective, I might move towards *shut-down* as in "a shut-down factory".

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=%22was+shutdown%22&hl=en&tbo=d&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=g2PxUJeSKIT8rAeJhoGwDQ&ved=0CAwQ_AUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1357700187,d.bmk&fp=9278ceb853d65c9a&biw=1024&bih=629